# How to make multiple Spring Webclient calls in parallel and wait for the result?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-webclient

I am new to Reactive programming and I would like to make two API calls in parallel and process the results and return a simple array or list of items.

I have two functions, one returns a Flux and the other returns a Mono and I make a very simple filtering logic on the Flux emitted items depending on the result of that Mono.

I tried to use `zipWith` but only one item made it to the end no matter what filtering logic. Also I tried with `block` but that is not allowed inside the controller :/

```
@GetMapping("/{id}/offers")
fun viewTaskOffers(
        @PathVariable("id") id: String,
        @AuthenticationPrincipal user: UserPrincipal
) : Flux<ViewOfferDTO> {
    data class TaskOfferPair(
        val task: TaskDTO,
        val offer: ViewOfferDTO
    )

    return client.getTaskOffers(id).map {
            it.toViewOfferDTO()
        }.zipWith(client.getTask(id), BiFunction {
            offer: ViewOfferDTO, task: TaskDTO -> TaskOfferPair(task, offer)
        }).filter {
            it.offer.workerUser.id == user.id || it.task.creatorUser == user.id
        }.map {
            it.offer
        }
}
```

- `getTaskOffers` returns a Flux of `OfferDTO`
- `getTask` returns a Mono of `TaskDTO`

If you cannot answer my question please tell me atleast how to do multiple API calls in parallel and wait for the results in WebClient

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a use case for a parallel call.

```
public Mono<UserInfo> fetchCarrierUserInfo(User user) {
        Mono<UserInfo> userInfoMono = fetchUserInfo(user.getGuid());
        Mono<CarrierInfo> carrierInfoMono = fetchCarrierInfo(user.getCarrierGuid());

        return Mono.zip(userInfoMono, carrierInfoMono).map(tuple -> {
            UserInfo userInfo = tuple.getT1();
            userInfo.setCarrier(tuple.getT2());
            return userInfo;
        });
    }
```

Here:

- `fetchUserInfo` makes http call to get user info from another service and returns `Mono`
- `fetchCarrierInfo` method makes HTTP call to get carrierInfo from another service and returns `Mono`
- `Mono.zip()` merges given monos into a new Mono that will be fulfilled when all of the given Monos have produced an item, aggregating their values into a Tuple2.

Then, call `fetchCarrierUserInfo().block()` it to get the final result.

Comment: What Could I use when these Monos are void. Thanks. I am getting these from here:  Mono<Void> values= Mono.fromRunnable(() -> setvalues(x, y, z));

Answer (score 1):

As you already figured out, `zipWith` won't help you there, since it will produce `min(a.size, b.size)`, which will always be 1, in case one of them is `Mono`.

But since those two are independent, you can simply split them:

```
val task: Mono<TaskDTO> = client.getTask(id)
val result: Flux<ViewOfferDTO> = 
task.flatMapMany {t ->
        client.getTaskOffers(id).map {offer ->
            t to offer
        }
    }.filter {
        it.second.workerUser.id == user.id || it.first.creatorUser == user.id
    }.map {
        it.second
}
```

Note that if you want to have pair of elements, you can use built-in `Pair`.

Also, this check doesn't make much sense, since you have only `Mono`: `it.first.creatorUser`

Comment: Also `getTaskOffers` returns a `Flux` so mapping it will return a single offer and not offers

Comment: Remember, I don't have your actual code, so I can't be 100% accurate. Still, I expanded my answer. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Convert your Mono to a Flux using [repeat()](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#repeat--):

```
client.getTask(id).cache().repeat();
```

So your code would become

```
    return client.getTaskOffers(id).map {
        it.toViewOfferDTO()
    }.zipWith(client.getTask(id).cache().repeat(), BiFunction {
        offer: ViewOfferDTO, task: TaskDTO -> TaskOfferPair(task, offer)
    }).filter {
        it.offer.workerUser.id == user.id || it.task.creatorUser == user.id
    }.map {
        it.offer
    }
```